# Unexpected behaviour of Space in InputFilter

Tags: android, android-layout

I want that no one put space in my edit text and I did this by using input filter but here is another problem that I faced is when I press space two time space button acting as backspace and delete the character that user entered already. I will thankful if someone solve this issue.
The code is : 
This is where i set input filter to my editText.

```
 etDrivenByEmail.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
                UtilityOfActivity.spaceNotAllowedInEditText()});
    }
```

This is my global input filter method:

```
public static InputFilter spaceNotAllowedInEditText(){

        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                       Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
```

This is the xml for my editText:

```
  <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editDrivenByMailID"
                        style="@style/editTextDefault"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:hint="@string/email"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_navy_blue" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Please try this code.

    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    String result = edittext.getText().toString().trim() + s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
                    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
                        edittext.setText(result);
                    }
else{
edittext.setSelection(0);
}
                }
            });

    It's working fine.
```

Comment: But in this whn I press space it take me at starting of the edittext I want my cursor at the starting of the edittext.